# sequelize.js hook afterBulkCreate iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having problems getting an `afterBulkCreate` hook to work using promises. Its being fired, but I get strange errors. I don't know if it is from the Model or from the promises being executed.

After the bulk create it should iterate through all instances and execute some further promise. I add them to the promise array and wait until they are all done and resolve the main promise. Is the code alright? Anyone see any errors?

```
'use strict';

var Q = require('q');
var _ = require('lodash')


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Transaction = sequelize.define('transaction', {

    // fields defined

  },{
    hooks: {
      afterBulkCreate: function(transactions, options) {
        console.log('after afterBulkCreate transaction')
        var promiseArray = [];
        _.each(transactions,function(value,index){
           var promiseone = sendOfApromsie(value.id)
          promiseArray.push(promiseone)
          // second promise
          var promisetwo = sendOfApromsie(value.id)
          promiseArray.push(promisetwo)
        })

        Q.all(promiseArray).then(function(){
          sequelize.Promise.resolve()
        })

      }
    }
  });

  return Transaction;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the promise for the hook to wait for it. You could also make the code much simpler by taking q and lodash out of the picture:

```
  var Transaction = sequelize.define('transaction', {

    // fields defined

  },{
    hooks: {
      afterBulkCreate: function(transactions, options) {
        return sequelize.Promise.map(transactions,function(value,index){
          var promiseone = sendOfApromsie(value.id)
          // second promise
          var promisetwo = sendOfApromsie(value.id)
          return sequelize.Promise.join(promiseone, promisetwo)
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

By mapping over the transactions array, you return a new promise - which contains two promises - and once all those are resolved, the hook is done

Comment: Thx for the help. I use Q because the sequelize documenation is not very good. Example like these really help. Thx